# pluginlib/class_loader does not load the correct class

Tags: ros, moveit, ikfast, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

For background, I'm trying to create two IKFast plugins for MoveIt! The problem I have is that MoveIt! only loads and uses one of the plugins. (I have confirmed this with print statements and have followed the trail all the way down to this [line (github source code)](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/blob/indigo-devel/planning/kinematics_plugin_loader/src/kinematics_plugin_loader.cpp#L145) of the "kinematics_plugin_loader.cpp" file of MoveIt!

This is the line of code:

```
result.reset(kinematics_loader_->createUnmanagedInstance(it->second[i]));
```

It uses the `pluginlib::ClassLoader`  of ROS.

To try and figure what is going on, I place some print statements around the code. I print out the library path and the argument name and everything looks OK (The names are different and the library paths are different). Yet when I call the method - named "testing" - of each library. They output the same message. What they should do is output different messages. So, it clearly executing the same library... But this is strange because I print out the library path and its different...

I have no idea what going on... Can anyone help?

Billy

The code looks like this :

```
ROS_INFO_STREAM("trying to load - "<<it->second[i]);

result.reset(kinematics_loader_->createUnmanagedInstance(it->second[i]));

result->testing();

ROS_INFO_STREAM("printing path - "<<kinematics_loader_->getClassLibraryPath(it->second[i]));

ROS_INFO_STREAM("after - "<<it->second[i]);
```

The output looks like this:

```
[ INFO] [1427495868.777012914]: rviz version 1.11.7

[ INFO] [1427495868.777129943]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)

[ INFO] [1427495868.919105126]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED

[ INFO] [1427495868.919228039]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).

[ INFO] [1427495869.578403687]: trying to load - thex3_l1_kinematics/IKFastKinematicsPlugin

[ INFO] [1427495869.629037635]: this is a test plugin 1

[ INFO] [1427495869.675017046]: printing path - /home/billy/moveit/devel/lib//libthex3_l1_moveit_ikfast_plugin.so

[ INFO] [1427495869.675101183]: after - thex3_l1_kinematics/IKFastKinematicsPlugin

[ INFO] [1427495869.681656644]: this is a test plugin 1

[ INFO] [1427495869.681832825]: trying to load - thex3_r2_kinematics/IKFastKinematicsPlugin

[ INFO] [1427495869.681905655]: this is a test plugin 1

[ INFO] [1427495869.730896859]: printing path - /home/billy/moveit/devel/lib//libthex3_r2_moveit_ikfast_plugin.so

[ INFO] [1427495869.730995835]: after - thex3_r2_kinematics/IKFastKinematicsPlugin

[ INFO] [1427495869.737139491]: this is a test plugin 1

[ INFO] [1427495871.880978103]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'

[ INFO] [1427495871.891378640]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206117/pluginlib/class_loader-does-not-load-the-correct-class./) by [auldwin1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21870/auldwin1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2015-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-28**:
I've seen other posts about issues trying to use multiple different IKFast plugins in MoveIt. Can't find them now though. If you really feel this is a bug (either in MoveIt, or in pluginlib), I suggest you post an issue on their respective issue trackers on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved!!! It's not a bug, I had to rename the classes manually. Ahhhh nothing feelings better than figuring out a problem after days slaving away at it...

---

Originally posted by [auldwin1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21870/auldwin1/) with karma: 81 on 2015-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PizzaTime](https://answers.ros.org/users/24999/pizzatime/) on 2016-04-18**:
Hello! can you please say what classes you have changed?  I currently have the same problem and cant find any solutions

**Comment by [PizzaTime](https://answers.ros.org/users/24999/pizzatime/) on 2016-04-18**:
awesome i got it :-) you can see my post for solution http://answers.ros.org/question/232142/problem-when-using-multiple-moveit-ikfast-plugins/